# Can't install nuget package provider in powershell core 7.0

Tags: azure, powershell

I am new to Azure and have issues trying to install NuGet Package Provider on PowerShell Core 7.0

```
Install-PackageProvider: Unhandled Exception - Message:'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType' threw an exception.' Name:'TypeInitializationException' Stack Trace:'   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicType.Create(Type tInterface, OrderedDictionary`2 instanceMethods, List`2 delegateMethods, List`1 stubMethods, List`2 usedInstances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.CreateProxy(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast(Type tInterface, Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterface.DynamicCast[TInterface](Object[] instances)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Plugin.DynamicInterfaceExtensions.As[TInterface](Object instance)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.get_PackageManagementHost()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletBase.SelectProviders(String[] names)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider.get_SelectedProviders()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.<get_CachedSelectedProviders>b__23_0()
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.DictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue](IDictionary`2 dictionary, TKey key, Func`1 valueFunction)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.Singleton`1.GetOrAdd(Func`1 newInstance, Object primaryKey, Object[] keys)
   at Microsoft.PackageManagement.Internal.Utility.Extensions.SingletonExtensions.GetOrAdd[TResult](Object primaryKey, Func`1 newInstance, Object[] keys)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.get_CachedSelectedProviders()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.CmdletWithProvider.GenerateDynamicParameters()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.AsyncCmdlet.<>c__DisplayClass83_0.<AsyncRun>b__0()'
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add the command you ran that generated this error.

Comment: Hello

Every command to install a package or module fail, if I run Get-PackageProvider fails too

Comment: What's your OS? Win 10? If so, what is the windows version?